# How do I have a template class object as a member of a non-template class in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm relatively new to templates in C++, and I'm having trouble understanding how to handle the following situation. I'm given a template class Reader that deduces its arguments from a template class Layout object passed to the constructor, like this:

```
template<typename ...Args>
class Layout {};

template<typename ...Args>
class Reader {
  public:
    Reader(Layout<Args...> layout);
};
```

Given a specific instantiation of `Layout`:

`using ALayout = Layout<int, double>;`

I would like to create a new, non-template class `AReaderHolder` that has a member variable of type `Reader` with `ALayout` as its layout. How can I do this without making `AReaderHolder` itself a class template?

I tried this:

```
class AReaderHolder {
  public:
    AReaderHolder() :
      _reader{ALayout{}} {}

  private:
    Reader _reader;
}
```

and got this error:

> use of class template 'Reader' requires template arguments;
> argument deduction not allowed in non-static class member

Which is fair, but what should I put for template arguments for the declaration for `_reader`? The problem as I see it is that `Reader` is templated on the parameter pack passed to `Layout`, and I don't know how to reference just that...

EDIT:
I recognize that I could just do something like

```
using AReader = Reader<int, double>;
```

And then just declare `_reader` to be of type `AReader`. But it feels clunky to manually specify the same parameter pack for `ALayout` and `AReader` (imagine the parameter pack is quite long and complex). Is there a way to do something like:

```
K = ???;
using ALayout = Layout<K>;
using AReader = Reader<K>;
```

To guarantee that `ALayout` and `AReader` are using the same parameter pack?

Comment: You could just declare the member as `Reader<int, double> _reader;`

Comment: I have edited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76301771/6309) to address your edit

Comment: Sometimes patience pays back. The best among all answers was @HNTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [cpp / class template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template), I see the issue comes from the fact that `Reader` is a template class, and it requires template arguments when you are declaring an instance of it in your `AReaderHolder` class.

In your case, since you have already defined `ALayout` as `Layout<int, double>`, you can use it as the template argument for `Reader`.

For instance:

```cpp
class AReaderHolder
{
    public:
        AReaderHolder() :
            _reader{ALayout{}}
        {}

    private:
        Reader<int, double> _reader; // Using ALayout template arguments here
};
```

In the above code, `_reader` is an instance of `Reader<int, double>`, because `ALayout` is an alias for `Layout<int, double>`.
This way, `AReaderHolder` does not need to be a template class, and the template arguments for `Reader` are provided explicitly based on your `ALayout` definition.

---

The reason we have `Reader<int, double> _reader;` instead of `Reader<Layout<int, double>> _reader;` has to do with how the `Reader` class template is defined.

Looking at your initial `Reader` definition:

```cpp
template<typename ...Args>
class Reader 
{
  public:
    Reader(Layout<Args...> layout);
};
```

The template parameters for `Reader` are not a `Layout` object, but rather the types that are used to instantiate `Layout`. In the constructor, an object of `Layout<Args...>` is passed, but the `Args...` in `Reader` and `Layout` are the same.

So, when we instantiate `Reader`, we need to provide the types that we would use to instantiate `Layout`, not the `Layout` itself. Therefore, we use `Reader<int, double> _reader;` because `int` and `double` are the types that are used to instantiate `Layout` (i.e., `ALayout`).

---

To resume: `AReaderHolder` is a non-template class that has a member variable `_reader` of type `Reader<int, double>`. This `Reader<int, double>` is the instantiation of the `Reader` template class that corresponds to the `Layout<int, double>` or `ALayout` that you have defined.

To be more precise, if you want to make sure that `_reader` is specifically associated with `ALayout`, you could potentially define a type alias for `Reader<int, double>` and use that in `AReaderHolder`:

```cpp
using AReader = Reader<int, double>;

class AReaderHolder
{
    public:
        AReaderHolder() :
            _reader{ALayout{}}
        {}

    private:
        AReader _reader;
};
```

This way, it's clear that `_reader` is the version of `Reader` that corresponds to `ALayout`. However, under the hood, `AReader` is still an instantiation of the `Reader` template class with the same arguments as `ALayout`.

---

> Is there a way to do something like:
>
> ```cpp
> K = ???;
> using ALayout = Layout<K>;
> using AReader = Reader<K>;
> ```
>
> To guarantee that `ALayout` and `AReader` are using the same parameter pack?

I do not think you can assign a type (or a set of types, in the case of a parameter pack) to a variable like `K` in your example.

Maybe a type alias would help in your case:

```cpp
template<typename ...Args>
using ALayout = Layout<Args...>;

template<typename ...Args>
using AReader = Reader<Args...>;

// Now you can define your types as
using MyLayout = ALayout<int, double>;
using MyReader = AReader<int, double>;
```

In this example, `MyLayout` and `MyReader` are both using the same parameter pack, and you only have to specify it once.
If you need to change the parameter pack, you only have to change it in one place.
However, note that `MyLayout` and `MyReader` are still separate types, and changing the definition of one will not automatically change the other.

---

Reading about [type trait](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/quick-primer-type-traits-modern-cpp), I suppose you can use a type trait to extract the types from the `Layout` and use them to define `Reader`.
A type trait is a template that operates on types, and it can be used to define type transformations or to extract information about a type.

For your case, you can define a type trait that extracts the parameter pack from `Layout` and applies it to `Reader`, like:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct LayoutToReader;  // Forward declaration

template<typename ...Args>
struct LayoutToReader<Layout<Args...>> {
    using type = Reader<Args...>;
};

// Now you can define AReader like this:
using AReader = LayoutToReader<ALayout>::type;
```

In this example, `LayoutToReader` is a type trait that transforms a `Layout` into a corresponding `Reader`. It does this by specializing for `Layout<Args...>` and defining a `type` member that is `Reader<Args...>`. Then, you can use this type trait to define `AReader` based on `ALayout`.

This way, you don't need to manually specify the same parameter pack for `ALayout` and `AReader`. If `ALayout` changes, `AReader` will automatically change to match it. This is a more robust solution that works even if the parameter pack is long and complex.

Comment: Thank you, VonC! It seems I can't do exactly what I want (specifically, specify a parameter pack and reuse it per my question), but your answer solves my problem by allowing me to specify the parameter pack just once and make sure that the reader changes when the layout changes.

Comment: @flyfisher True, from what I understand, template parameters are a compile-time concept and are not variables that can be assigned values or passed around. They must be provided at the point of declaration and cannot be stored or reused in the way you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Sticking to the plan of making an `AReader` alias:

```
class AReaderHolder {
    AReader _reader;
public:
    AReaderHolder() : _reader{ALayout{}} { }
};
```

The question is how to define `AReader` neatly.

You could try to use class template argument deduction:

```
using AReader = decltype(Reader(std::declval<ALayout>()));
// this line says: "Imagine you have an ALayout. Then imagine making a Reader from this imaginary object. Take the type of this imaginary Reader and call it AReader."
```

This depends on `Reader` having template-deduction friendly constructors/deduction guides. For the skeleton you've posted, this works.

Another idea is to have `Layout` itself expose the correct `Reader` type:

```
template<typename ...Args>
class Reader; // necessary forward declaration

template<typename... Args>
struct Layout {
    using ReaderType = Reader<Args...>;
};

using AReader = ALayout::ReaderType;
```

A robust solution that doesn't involve changing `Layout` is a type trait:

```
template<typename T>
struct ReaderForLayout;
template<typename... Args>
struct ReaderForLayout<Layout<Args...>> { using type = Reader<Args...>; };
template<typename T>
using ReaderForLayout_t = typename ReaderForLayout<T>::type;

using AReader = ReaderForLayout_t<ALayout>;
```

(If I ever found myself writing a type trait like this one, though, I would reconsider my design choices.)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to explicitly declare the template parameter for `Reader`.

```cpp
class AReaderHolder
{
    public:
        AReaderHolder() :
            _reader{ALayout{}}
  {}

    private:
        Reader<Layout<int,double>> _reader;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simpler approach than the so far suggested would be to parameterize `Reader` not on `...Args` but on `Layout`:

```
template <typename Layout>
class Reader { /* ... */ };
```

Then you can just instantiate `Reader` on `ALayout`:

```
class AReaderHolder {
  public:
    AReaderHolder() :
      _reader{ALayout{}} {}

  private:
    Reader<ALayout> _reader;
};
```

If you need access to the template arguments `...Args` of `ALayout` in the definition of `Reader`, you can specialize it and leave the primary template undefined:

```
template <typename Layout>
class Reader;

template <typename... T>
class Reader<Layout<T...>> { /* Here you have access to `...Args` */ };
```